# Physical interpretation of $pV= 0$ for Einstein Crystal Model

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry, crystals

> There is a difficulty with the pressure of the Einstein crystal model. The model does not include any simple way to evaluate the derivative in Eq. (28.2-7e). We might try to
> evaluate the pressure by finding the difference between G and A, since G = A + PV .
> For a one-component system, G is given Eq. (26.1-29) as
> \begin{aligned}
> G &=N \mu=U_{0}-3 N k_{\mathrm{B}} T \ln (z) \\
> &=U_{0}+3 N k_{\mathrm{B}} T \ln \left(1-e^{-h v / k_{\mathrm{B}} T}\right)
> \end{aligned}
> so that G = A, which leads to PV = 0
> $$P=k_{\mathrm{B}} T\left(\frac{\partial \ln (\mathcal{Z})}{\partial V}\right)_{T}=3 N k_{\mathrm{B}} T\left(\frac{\ln (z)}{\partial V}\right)_{T} \text{(Eq.28.2-7e)}$$

$$A=-k_{\mathrm{B}} T \ln (\mathcal{Z})=U_{0}+3 N k_{\mathrm{B}} T \ln \left(1-e^{-h v / k_{\mathrm{B}} T}\right)$$

The paragraph ist from Physical Chemistry Mortimer. My interpretation is as follow:

The term $pV$ represents the work that would required to “make room” for the system by pushing the atmospheric pressure. Thus, in a way, the Einstein Model suggests the solid exists in a vacuum (where $p=0$ ) because the solid, of course, does have a volume!

The professor said it is wrong. She said the term $pV=0$ is not a big problem for the Einstein Crystal Model because there is not much change in the volume of a crystal with reference to $p\cdot \Delta V = 0$. I feel unsatisfied with the argument since the book refers to $pV = 0$ and not $p\cdot \Delta V = 0$. So what's is the right way to interpret this?

Answer (score 0):

To me, the book has the clearest justification, which you don't mention:

> "...for a crystal the numerical value of PV is small compared with G and A, so that we can use the formulas for G and A to an adequate approximation."

You present a more exact but more restrictive constraint: P (and therefore PV) is exactly zero. This is fine if it works for the problem.

I agree that your professor's argument (i.e., that PΔV is generally negligible) isn't relevant here, although the statement may also be true. As you note, ΔV is different from V.

Comment: hi I'm not so sure why you include the quote "...for a crystal the numerical value of PV is small compared with G and A, so that we can use the formulas for G and A to an adequate approximation." I saw it but thought it's not that relevant to the post so didnt include it. Can you explain why you find the quote important?

Comment: Hi! Your question above is "So what's is the right way to interpret this?" I'm assuming by "this" you mean "the fact that $PV$ is taken as zero in this textbook derivation". The quote is Mortimer's explanation: $PV\ll G$ and $PV\ll A$, so $G=A+PV\approx A$. Did you mean something else by "this"?

Comment: yes exactly. What I understood is that in real-life situation, $p\cdot V$ is small but non zero and $G= A +PV$ can therefore be approximated with simply $A$. So my point is that i understood what the quote you included means mathematically. Though I'm not sure how it is related to my original question 'How to interpret $PV=0$ in Einstein Crystal Model' so I didnt include the quote in my post. Hence, I would like to know why you think the quote clarifies my question.

Comment: The interpretation is that the equivalence is exact when the pressure is zero.